# How to change MySQL environment in vagrant server?

Tags: mysql, vagrant

What are the correct steps to change the MySQL environment in vagrant?

Answer (score 1):

Yes I found the correct steps to solve this.
Type these command in command prompt

1. vagrant up
2. vagrant ssh
3. mysql -u usernameOfMysql -p
4. enter the password.
5. Change to the database-> use databaseName
6. Copy the mysql code
7. show tables